# Jquery with while loop error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use the while loop inside events:[] block. This below code is working but if i use inside event block it shows blank page.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();
    var i = 1;
    while (i <= 10) {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            editable: true,
            events: [{
                title: 'All Day Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, i)
            }]
        });
        i++;
    }
});
```

Comment: If the code is working, what's the problem exactly? If you're doing something else that then breaks it, show us *that* code.

Comment: Actually i want to display the full calender with events marked on the date. i am using the above script alone with some js files and html div tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a function that returns an array instead, and do a loop inside there.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        editable: true,
        events: function(){
           var arr = [];
           for(var i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
              arr.push({
                  title: 'All Day Event',
                  start: new Date(y,m,i)
              });
           }
           return arr;
        }() // <-- Here we execute the function, so it evaluates as an array.
    });
```